# Does any bounded set $A$ have bounded boundary $\partial A$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be any metric space. And $A\subseteq X$ is a bounded set.

Does it mean $\partial A$, the boundary of $A$, is also bounded? It seems it will be bounded. But to prove that, I am confused how to approach it. Any hint is welcome.

Comment: Start at the top. What does it mean for a set to be bounded?

Comment: @UmbertoP. mean finite diameter.

Comment: OK. Next what does it mean for a point to belong to the boundary of a set $A$?

Comment: if $x$ is in boundary set . then every ball around $x$ will intersect set $A$ as well as its complement

Comment: You have the definitions down. Now show that if $x,y \in \partial A$ then $d(x,y) < \mathop{\rm diam} A + 2$. You can do this by finding points $a$ and $b$ in $A$ that are within distance $1$ of $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Comment: thanks.i got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't *mean* that. For instance, in $\mathbb R$ (with the usual metric), $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is unbounded, but its boundary is $\{0\}$, which is bounded.

However, it is true that the boundary of a bounded set $A$ is always bounded. That's because $A\subset B(a,r)$ for some $a\in X$ and some $r>0$, and therefore the boundary of $A$ is contained in the closed ball centered at $a$ with radius $r$.

Comment: this is exactly my question.if set is bounded. then how does it imply boundary set is also bounded

Comment: @paarth Then I suppose that I've answered your question.